# How to style active NavLink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, chakra-ui

How can I make the active `NavLink` look similar to this? I tried following the React-Router-Dom docs but it didn't give this desired look. Is it possible to pass the `isActive` prop from the `NavLink` component to the `Flex` component? I created a minimum representation of the sidebar down below. I'd appreciate any help.

[image]

Here's a minimal recreation of the sidebar made using Chakra UI:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sidebar-ckm26m?file=/src/index.js

```
//imports

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Stack spacing={4}>
      <NavLink to="/overview">
        <Flex align="center" p="2" mx="2" ...>
          <Box p="4px" border="1px" ...>
            <AiOutlineDashboard size={16} />
          </Box>
          <Box ml={2} fontSize="sm">
            Overview
          </Box>
        </Flex>
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink to="/app">
        <Flex align="center" p="2" mx="2" ...>
          <Box p="4px" border="1px" ...>
            <IoApps size={16} />
          </Box>
          <Box ml={2} fontSize="sm">
            Apps
          </Box>
        </Flex>
      </NavLink>
    </Stack>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass the `isActive` prop from the `NavLink` component to
> the `Flex` component?

Yes, it is entirely possible. The `NavLink` component understands and knows how to match the active route, there's no need to reinvent the wheel by using the `useLocation` hook and manually checking the current `pathname`.

The `NavLink` component's [`children`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link#children) prop can take a render function that is passed the `isActive` prop.

Example Implementation:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Box
      bg="white"
      borderRight="1px"
      w="200px"
      pos="fixed"
      overflow="auto"
      h="full"
    >
      <Stack spacing={4}>
        <NavLink to="/overview">
          {({ isActive }) => ( // <-- children render function
            <LinkContainer
              icon={<IoApps size={16} />}
              isActive={isActive} // <-- pass isActive through as prop
              label="Overview"
            />
          )}
        </NavLink>

        <NavLink to="/app">
          {({ isActive }) => (
            <LinkContainer
              icon={<AiOutlineDashboard size={16} />}
              isActive={isActive}
              label="Apps"
            />
          )}
        </NavLink>
      </Stack>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

```
const LinkContainer = ({ icon, isActive, label }) => (
  <Flex
    align="center"
    p="2"
    mx="2"
    borderRadius="lg"
    role="group"
    fontSize="14px"
    cursor="pointer"
    {...(isActive // <-- conditionally apply active props/styling/etc
      ? {
          bg: "#002c8a",
          color: "#fff",
          borderColor: "#002c8a"
        }
      : {})}
    _hover={{
      bg: "#f5f5f5",
      color: "#002c8a",
      borderColor: "#002c8a"
    }}
  >
    <Box
      p="4px"
      border="1px"
      borderRadius="full"
      borderColor="gray.200"
      fontSize="26"
    >
      {icon}
    </Box>
    <Box ml={2} fontSize="sm">
      {label}
    </Box>
  </Flex>
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply different styles based on your current path, one way of achieving this is by using `useLocation()` which gives you the current path.

Make sure you make an array of your items so you can map over them and apply the necessary changes when it's the selected path.

Now if I apply this concept to the code your provided on sandbox, my App.js should look like this

```
import { Stack, Flex, Box } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { AiOutlineDashboard } from "react-icons/ai";
import { IoApps } from "react-icons/io5";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const items = [
  {
    label: "Overview",
    path: "/overview",
    icon: <AiOutlineDashboard size={16} />
  },
  {
    label: "Apps",
    path: "/app",
    icon: <IoApps size={16} />
  }
];

const App = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  return (
    <Box
      bg="white"
      borderRight="1px"
      w="200px"
      pos="fixed"
      overflow="auto"
      h="full"
    >
      <Stack spacing={4}>
        {items.map((item) => {
          const isSelected = item.path === pathname;
          return (
            <NavLink key={item.path} to={item.path}>
              <Flex
                align="center"
                p="2"
                mx="2"
                borderRadius="lg"
                role="group"
                fontSize="14px"
                cursor="pointer"
                background={isSelected && "#012D89"}
                color={isSelected && "#fff"}
                _hover={
                  !isSelected && {
                    bg: "#f5f5f5",
                    color: "#002c8a",
                    borderColor: "#002c8a"
                  }
                }
              >
                <Box
                  p="4px"
                  border="1px"
                  borderRadius="full"
                  borderColor="gray.200"
                  fontSize="26"
                >
                  {item.icon}
                </Box>
                <Box ml={2} fontSize="sm">
                  {item.label}
                </Box>
              </Flex>
            </NavLink>
          );
        })}
        ;
      </Stack>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And it looks like that

[image: screenshot of solution]

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS selector with with pseudo class of active, within the pseudo class you can change the BG color

```css
button:active {
  background-color: green; /* Change the background color to green when the button is active */
  border: 2px solid darkgreen; /* Add a border to the button when it's active */
}
```